# How do I build a Program that accesses an online script

Tags: php, c++

I want to write a program to contact a PHP script online, and show the HTML output. Basically, it will be a browser that only access the programmed URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Seva's answer but a little better integrated with the Windows GUI. I would put together a simple HTA that used JavaScript to load the required page into an IFRAME. HTA's are executable and provide a simple GUI that is basically IE without all of the controls.

A google search for "[Microsoft HTA](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=microsoft%20hta&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk)" should get you going, clearly you already know HTML so putting an HTA together will be easy as it is just HTML and some scripting in either JavaScript or VBscript.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a program. Just execute the URL as a file. In Windows, that'll open the browser. If you need to ship at least something, ship a BAT file with the following contents:

```
@start http://www.mysite.com/
```

The builtin `start` command means "find the right executable for the specified parameter and call it, passing the parameter to it". The default browser is the one registered to handle the http schema.

Or you can ship a URL shortcut. To make one, open the site in IE, and drag from the address bar to the desktop. That'll give you a file with a .URL extension that you can 
"execute", either from the shell or from the command line.

Comment: Either of these methods has the disadvantage that the user ends up with the full IE GUI and can therefore navigate off the chosen page. If this is important to stop, using an HTA is a better solution. It is also better integrated into the Windows GUI.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if there is a PHP or Python or anything else on server because scripts give their output in HTML.
What you need is some kind of HTTP-client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: Windows already has a perfectly acceptable HTTP/HTML library set, libcurl is not required.